why Interactive grid not saving the data calculated by java script code?
I have interactive grid based on this query :
select     id_no,
           TESTID, 
           UNITID , 
           result,
           MEAN,
           SD,
           ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2) AS SDI ,
           LOW_LIMIT,
           HIGH_LIMIT,
           PERF_ID, 
           VALIDATED
FROM HAJJ_QC_RESULTS 
where sample_id = :P13_SAMPLE
AND hospital_no = :P13_HOSPITAL
AND approved_date = :P13_FROMDATE

Then I created button with dynamic action
when click the button I need to calculate  PERF_ID column
this is the java script code and the button working when click the button
its calculating the data in the grid this is the code executed with dynamic action
var widget = apex.region('validate').widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;
var v_amount = 0; 

model.forEach(function (r) {

    v_amount = 0; 
    model.setValue(r,'VALIDATED',2)
    
if (model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= 0 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 1 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 1
      model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      
      
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 0 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= -1 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 1
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= 1.01 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 1.5 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 2
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= -1.01 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= -1.5 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 2
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= 1.6 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 2 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 3
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= -1.6 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= -2 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 3
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") > 2 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 4
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") < -2 ) 
{
      v_amount += 4
       model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
v_amount = 0; 
})

the issue when I click save button its not saving PERF_ID column data
I checked the DML process I have only one editable region
what is the reason why not saving the data ?
Note : if I type the data in column PERF_ID one by oy one for every row and save its saving but
when the data fill by java script code its not saving it ?

Use:
model.setValue(r,'PERF_ID',v_amount.toString())

From https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aexjs/model.html :
‘The model has very few restrictions on the values of fields. However typically when the model data is backing APEX items or HTML form controls the values will all be strings.’
Server side, APEX will convert to a number, taking into account any format mask.

I will try it thank you , I solved it by using CASE in query

I solved it by using CASE in query dynamic and no need for the button
select     id_no,
           TESTID, 
           UNITID , 
           result,
           MEAN,
           SD,
           ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2) AS SDI ,
           LOW_LIMIT,
           HIGH_LIMIT,
           CASE WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   >= 0 
                AND  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)  <= 1 )
           THEN 1
                WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   <= 0  
                AND  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)  >= -1 )
           THEN 1
                WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   >= 1.01 
                AND  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2) <= 1.5 )
           THEN 2
                WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   <= -1.01 
                AND  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)  >= -1.5 )
           THEN 2
                WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   >= 1.6  
                AND  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)  <= 2 )
           THEN 3
                WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   <= -1.6 
                AND  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   >= -2 )
           THEN 3
                WHEN (ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2)   > 2 
                OR  ROUND(((result - mean) / sd),2) < -2 )
           THEN 4
           ELSE 0 END AS  PERF_ID, 
           2 AS VALIDATED
FROM HAJJ_QC_RESULTS 
where sample_id = :P13_SAMPLE
AND hospital_no = :P13_HOSPITAL
AND approved_date = :P13_FROMDATE

